# Difference between !(a==b) and a!=b

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison, equality

Last week in high school my IT teacher gave us a programm, where one part she wrote interested me a lot.
In an if-statement, she checked if an element of an array was not null, so the programm could proceed with this element, therefore she wrote:
`if (!(array[i] == null)`, which confused me, because with this method you are just using a bracket more, which makes it less easy to read. I changed it to `ìf (array[i] != null)` and it worked just fine. But now I am confused, because as a teacher I assume you know a lot of your subject, so could there be a good reason why she used her method over mine? Is there some detail I don't know about?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to write the former.

Comment: The expressions are equivalent, so just take the one that's easier to read... and make sure to be consistent within your code / project. Alternating things like that in a single project is likely to cause errors.

Comment: It's all about readability. Some teams prefer to use `!=` while others would go for `!...==`

Comment: In Java `(a!=b)` and `!(a==b)` are equivalent, because Java does not provide any way to alter the behaviour of those operators from the defaults.

Comment: When someone has a lot of experience, they've had lots of opportunities to pick up lots of quirks and habits from lots of different languages. People usually write code in the way that works for them, doesn't mean it's better for you.

Comment: Why not just ask her?

Comment: It's just a personal preference. Do ask your teacher if there is any particular reason behind, your teacher might appreciate your approach of thinking differently. Good Luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference in the semantics of the two expressions. I would say there is no good reason to ever write the former.

> But now I am confused, because as a teacher I assume you know a lot of your subject, so could there be a good reason why she used her method over mine?

The best thing to do is to ask your teacher. The most important thing to remember about teachers - as human beings - is that they have experiences, prejudices and are fallible.

In other words, she might have been bitten by some problem in the past which was solved by writing it like this - ask her about it, you might learn something.

Or, she perhaps thinks it's better, and can't articulate a strong benefit over personal preference; or that was the way she learnt, and hasn't seen a strong need to change - you learn something from that, insofar as there is more than one way to articulate the same semantics.

(I have a strong preference for `!=` because it's neater - fewer parentheses; and why would the language designers bother providing `!=` if you weren't intended to use it - but these are *my* personal preferences).

Or, she maybe meant to use `!=`, and forgot to go back to fix it. It's easy to forget to clean things up.

Comment: Great answer. I would add, that teachers tend to make examples clearer. I assume that in case of teaching Boolean algebra, it is easier to explain != condition as !(==) to some students, maybe that was the reason to write the latter

Answer (score 4):

In Java, there is no difference between `a!=b` and `!(a==b)`. Choosing the later form is a stylistic choice, which, to be honest, most static analysis tools/IDEs will issue a warning about.

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is using other ways to write the if-statement.

It doesn't matter if you write

```java
if(array[i] != null)
```

or

```java
if(!(array[i] == null))
```

because `!` defines as  **not**  in most programming language. In this situation both of them are equal.

In conclusion, you can choose whatever style you like.

Hope you understood and good luck!

Always ask your teacher when you wonder about something :)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct. For your example there is no difference - chose what you like the most. But I'd like to give some more reasons to chose one way over the others.

My advice would be **not** to go for `if (! (...))` in general because:

- Most people wouldn't do it like this. You will have to read and understand code written by others and others will have to read and understand your code. Quirks like that greatly reduce the redability and collegues will frown upon you.
- Some projects might follow a coding standard that doesn't allow this.
- Think about the execution. For more complex statements the different style might have an impact. Think of `!(A || B || C || D)` vs `!A && !B && !C && !D`. It might happen that in the former A-D have to be evaluated and then the resulting boolean is flipped wheras in the latter it might be enough to see that `!A` evaluates to false and you can already stop there (because any conjunction with a `false` member will be `false`).
- But also think about readability again. Actually it might be easier to grasp writing `NOT(is_a_digit OR is_a_letter OR is_a_dot)` instead of
  `NOT(is_a_digit) AND NOT(is_a_letter) AND NOT(is_a_dot)`.
- That being said, it's also good to know about Yoda-style writing which is kinda related. Imagine you have `String someString;` that might contain a string or might be `null`. Now imagine you'd like to check if its equal to `"some specific string"`: `someString.equals("some specific string")` - yikes, this might produce a NPE because when `someString` is null there is no method `equals` to call on it. Instead you'd have to do `someString != null && someString.equals("...")` or the Yoda-way of `"some specific string".equals(someString)`. There's also other helpers like `Objects.equals()`.

Sometimes extra parenthesis can make things easier to grasp and sometimes they don't.

While I don't agree that "there are no stupid question" I'd say that sometimes it's better to ask a dumb question than falling behind in the lessons because something nags at you or you missed some important bit. In this case I'd consider this a good question (unless she just told you why).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `a!=b` and `!(a==b)`, it depends on personal preference and what code you're using. In python `a!=b` is faster, as other answers have stated.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is no difference between if (!(array[i] == null) and ìf (array[i] != null)

In this case we can imagine a scenario. Lets say array[i] is not null, then for the first expression inside if(!(false)) , eventually !(false) will be true.

And for the second expression the return result will be directly true.

So seconnd expression is recommended always.

Comment: This is !Cparta :)

Answer (score -2):

The former is not a good idea in some languages like python,
In python, for former the better way is

`if not something==somethingElse`

although for latter its perfect, `if something != somethingElse`,

So learning the former might get you in some situations where the bug is so subtle that debugging gets really hard, especially when you use this condition in `while` loop

Answer (score -2):

`!=` is more efficient than `!()`. I ran a test in python, and it speaks for itself.

```
(not a and not b and not c and not d) 10.07692837715149 

(not (a and b and c and d)) 11.208963394165039
```